# MySQLi acting out in functions

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to move from `MySQL`to`MySQLi`but am having some problems. My`SQLi`connection starts as shown below:

```
$langCon=mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'english');
if (!$langCon) die('Couldn\'t connect: '.mysqli_error());
```

and I am trying to use`MySQLi`to store my session data, however, I keep getting an error on my _write construct **(It is unfinished, posting like this since the error occurs on line 56, the one with`$stmt=...`)**:

```
function _write($id, $data){ /
        global $langCon;
        $stmt=mysqli_prepare($langCon,'REPLACE INTO `sess`(`id`,`access`,`data`) VALUES(?,?,?)');
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($langCon,$id);
        $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($langCon,$data);
        $t=$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
        return mysqli_query($langCon,"REPLACE INTO `sess`(`id`,`access`,`data`) VALUES('$id','$t','$data')");
    }
```

The error given is: `Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in [...]settings.php on line 56` (the line is $stmt=...)

Could anyone please tip me off on where my problem might be?

**EDIT**  Var dump outside function,`var_dump($langCon)`:

> object(mysqli)#2 (18) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(0) ["client_info"]=>
>   string(50) "mysqlnd 5.0.8-dev - 20102224 - $Revision: 321634 $"
>   ["client_version"]=> int(50008) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0)
>   ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) ""
>   ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "localhost via
>   TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(0) ["server_info"]=>
>   string(10) "5.5.21-log" ["server_version"]=> int(50521) ["stat"]=>
>   string(130) "Uptime: 373 Threads: 1 Questions: 5 Slow queries: 0
>   Opens: 34 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 27 Queries per second avg:
>   0.013" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(5) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) }

Var dump inside function, `global $langCon;   var_dump($langCon);`: NULL.

Comment: Try using it without $langCon at the beginning of the prepare?

Comment: Is your connection code within a function? Have you declared `$langCon` global there as well?

Comment: @Bono Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: @lanzz: my connection code isn't within a function. It is in the same file as `_write($id, $data)`.

Comment: And you are certain you're calling `_write()` _after_ you have connected? Because there is no way for us to know that from the code you posted.

Comment: `write()`is part of my session management and it worked fine until I moved to`MySQLi`.As for calling it after connecting, my page files all start with`require 'settings.php';`and that connection is the first line there.

Comment: @Limoncello are you doing it like $mysqli = new mysqli(); ? I think that's whats missing (see my answer)

Comment: I was doing it in the procedural style, which shouldn't really make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manual; try something like this (it has to look like $var->prepare)

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "english");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) 
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}

if (!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO test(id) VALUES (?)"))) 
{
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: Both my procedural style and your OO style work outside functions, however, when I try the OO style inside _write() I get `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object`

Comment: @Limoncello And $mysqli is set in that code? AKA you've got acces to it (I see you put $langCon as global, is $mysqli global?)

Comment: Yes, my `_write()` function begins with `global $langCon, $mysqli;`

Comment: @Limoncello Have you tried mysqli_prepare($mysqli, 'SQL'); ? Since it's asking for mysqli(). Also have you got all error reporting on?

Comment: Then I get `Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given` . That's the reason of my frustration here, I did everything according to the manual, declared everything that needs to be global as global, and still get errors.

Comment: @Limoncello Are you 100% postive all your specified connection variable etc are correct (user, password etc)

Comment: Yes I am, else the script would have died ( `if ($langCon==false) die('Couldn\'t connect: '.mysqli_error());` )

Comment: @Limoncello could you post a var_dump of $langCon? I think you somehow haven't got acces to it (hence it's NULL).

Comment: Of course. Updated my question, the dump wouldn't look very good in a comment box.

Comment: @Limoncello I'm not an expert with globals (never use them) but do you need to specify global $langCon in the function? Doesnt that reset it or something?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12732/discussion-between-limoncello-and-bono)